# mongodb how to change default port

Tags: mongodb

For my project I need to use mongodb on port 80.
In fact I can't use the default mongodb port (27017).
I must use port 80.

If I edit the config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/mongodb.conf
```

and I change the port to 80 then I restart mongodb service, I get this message when I try to connect to mongodb

```
$ mongo --port 80

MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:80/test
Fri Feb  6 14:16:42.705 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:80 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:147
exception: connect failed
```

If I change the port again to 27017, all work fine.

Can someone help me?

Comment: `mongod` is the main database service. `mongo` is just the cli interface. You need to restart `mongod`: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes

Comment: Have you added `port=80` in your config file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check if port is already open by another application or service:

on Windows, open `cmd` and type: `netstat -a`

on Linux, type: `netstat -lptn`

Look for open port 80, like `TCP 0.0.0.0:80`

If you can't find it, open `mongodb.conf` and change the `net` section:

```
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 80
```

I hope this help you

Comment: If i launch a node app on port 80 and mongodb on the same port it cannot work ?

Comment: A port can be used only for one app or service at a same time. I suggest you use another port for mongoDB