# Mongodb can't connect on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

when i run my app with this commande 
node app.js
I get this error:
connection error {MongoError: server localhost:8080 sockets closed }

**app.js**

```
var http=require('http');
var express=require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');   
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app=express();
var server=http.createServer(app);
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:8080/matest');

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  // we're connected!
  console.log('connected');

});

var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id    : String,
    name: String,
    age   : Number
});

var user = mongoose.model('emp', mySchema);
server.listen(port);
```

Comment: Are you sure your mongo is on 8080? Can you connect to it using console?

Comment: @AlexanderM. Who i know  mongo  has port 8080 ? i'm beginner

Comment: @AlexanderM. wheni run  db.runCommand({whatsmyuri : 1}) it's show  127.0.0.1,'ok',1} i want edite this ip to localhost:8080 , how please ?

Comment: @AlexanderM. when I run commande "mongod" I see this message waiting   for connections on port 27017

Comment: That means that 27017 in your port.

Comment: @AlexanderM. how can edit port ?

Comment: By default, mongo transports on 27017 port. 8080 is the port for HTTP. You can change your port to 8080 refering this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367791/mongodb-how-to-change-default-port

Comment: @AlexanderM. use `mongod --port xxx` to run MongoDB on _xxx_ port

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to use:

```
var db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost','test')
```

There is no need to set port since 27017 is the default port of mongo and mongoose knows it.
'test' is the database you use (as using mongdo, you needn;t create database previously)

8080 is the port of your website instead of mongodb.