# I Can't start the mongodb server

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I just installed MongoDb on Ubuntu 16.04 and I can not run the server. I get the following information when the "status" of the server (sudo systemctl start mongodb):

```
lmunoz@lmunoz:/var/www/node/dashboard$ sudo systemctl status mongodb
● mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented 
database
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor 
preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since mar 2017-05-09 12:01:59 PET; 
29s ago
Process: 1042 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config 
/etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=48)
Main PID: 1042 (code=exited, status=48)

may 09 12:01:59 lmunoz systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-
free document-oriented database.
may 09 12:01:59 lmunoz systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process 
exited, code=exited, status=48/n/a
may 09 12:01:59 lmunoz systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Unit entered 
failed state.
may 09 12:01:59 lmunoz systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 
'exit-code'.
```

The log (/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log) shows me the following:

```
listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 
127.0.0.1:27017
addr already in use
Failed to set up sockets during startup.
dbexit:  rc: 48
```

And my configuration file (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service) contains:

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to start mongodb local server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478113/unable-to-start-mongodb-local-server)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the logs you are having another service which is running on the port 27017.

Look for that service and stop it and then retry. Or if you don't care about the service running on that port, can do

```
sudo fuser -k 27017/tcp
```

Another alternative will be to change the default of mongodb. See [mongodb how to change default port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367791/mongodb-how-to-change-default-port)

Comment: Yes, I just had to restart my computer and it worked.

Comment: cool! Happy to hear that you got unstuck.